# Is there a way to copy a Windows program from an external HDD into WINE?

Tags: software-installation, wine, windows-10, 19.04

I am running Windows 10 on an external HDD.  I only use Windows for one program for work, otherwise, I use Ubuntu 19.04 (Dingo).  Is there a way to move or copy this program from my Windows HDD into WINE?

This program was installed by the IT dept at my client's office, so I don't have access to the installation media.  None of them know Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro), so it'll be easier if I don't have to involve them.

I want to be able to format the external HDD to use as just a drive instead of reserving it for just one program.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Ubuntu (and Wine) can read Windows HDDs. So why do you need to copy it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to move or copy this program from my Windows HDD into WINE?

Sure, you can copy the files to your WINE. WINE is a directory in your /home/$USER so you can copy files to that and see them in an explorer in WINE.

Mind though: copying it into WINE does NOT mean you can use that software. That depends on what the software is. Even if you did have the installation media it does not guarantee to work in WINE either.

Would it be an option to create an ISO from the external HDD and create a virtualbox VDI so you can use it virtually? Like https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-boot-and-install-from-iso-in-virtualbox/ That would also enable your software inside the container.

Comment: yes I think that might work!  Would that require creating an ISO for the entire drive, or could I just create it for Edge (the program)?

Comment: You would need the whole windows OS, but should only need to install your program.  If you know the name of the program, wine keeps a list of known programs that work in it, and those that don't.  Is that Edge as in the browser(might come to linux soon) or another program.

Comment: @crip659 The Edge I'm talking about is a dental software (not MS Edge/IE).

Comment: Doubt very much if wine will run that, your best bet would be to use virtualbox or VMware and install/copy windows on it.  VMs do like to use ram so you will need to decide if you have enough.  I would recommend at least 8GBs on computer so it does not slow down, you can get with less.